# Lightswitch Clickonce Deployment Issue

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have deployed a new version of a Lightswitch application. This application has 6 users in our organization. All 6 users had the previous version installed and working properly. 4 users have installed the update and use it without any issues. 2 users cannot launch the new version. During the installation, they receive the following error details:

**PLATFORM VERSION INFO**
    - Windows : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    - Common Language Runtime : 4.0.30319.1008
    - System.Deployment.dll : 4.0.30319.245 (RTMGDR.030319-2400)
    - clr.dll : 4.0.30319.1008 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    - dfdll.dll : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    - dfshim.dll : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

**SOURCES**
    - Deployment url : file:///F:/ETL/MetadataEditor/MetadataEditor.application
    - Application url : file:///F:/ETL/MetadataEditor/Application%20Files/MetadataEditor.exe.manifest

**IDENTITIES**
    - Deployment Identity : MetadataEditor.application, Version=1.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86
    - Application Identity : MetadataEditor.exe, Version=1.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

**APPLICATION SUMMARY**
    - Installable application.

**ERROR SUMMARY**
 Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    - Activation of F:\ETL\MetadataEditor\MetadataEditor.application resulted in exception.   Following failure messages were detected:
    - Strong name signature not valid for this assembly vslshost.exe.

**COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY**
 No transaction error was detected.

**WARNINGS**
    - The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    - The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    - The file named default.htm does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.
    - The file named web.config does not have a hash specified in the manifest. Hash validation will be ignored.

**OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS**
    - [2/24/2014 3:48:23 PM] : Activation of F:\ETL\MetadataEditor\MetadataEditor.application has started.
    - [2/24/2014 3:48:23 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    - [2/24/2014 3:48:23 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    - [2/24/2014 3:48:24 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    - [2/24/2014 3:48:29 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    - [2/24/2014 3:48:29 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

**ERROR DETAILS**
 Following errors were detected during this operation.
    - [2/24/2014 3:48:53 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
    - Strong name signature not valid for this assembly vslshost.exe.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
 at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyStrongNameAssembly(String filePath, AssemblyManifest assemblyManifest)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
 at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
 No transaction information is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install the .NET 4.5 framework, even if it is already installed. Whatever component was missing is installed with that. See this MSDN post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14fe4b23-a82e-4676-8028-905c9f943ded/desktop-application-installation-failure-vslshostexe-error?forum=lightswitch